# ASP.NET C# SQL Loop to Label

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, label

Is it possible to perform a SQL `SELECT` Statement that will select all rows, then output the rows to a label, which is created dynamically?

In the system I'm writing (pretty new to c#) I am performing a SQL `SELECT` from a view where a records ID can appear multiple times, but with different associated values, i.e.

```
ID - VALUE    
1 - A    
1 - B    
1 - C    
2 - A    
2 - B    
3 - A
```

What I want to do then is output each result to a its own label, but i would have no idea until the `SELECT` is ran how many labels I would need so I'd need code to draw them dynamically?  Using the above examples A would return 3 labels, but B would only return 2.

If that makes any sense? E.G

```
foreach (result in sql)
{
 label.Text = result
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should use a [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control to handle this.

Comment: What you want to do is certainly possible.  You need to research "dynamically create controls in asp.net".  However, if at all possible I would encourage you to find a way to display the data without creating controls.  Gridview and even repeaters are a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a repeater to do this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="labelRepeater" runat="server" 
      DataSourceID="labelDataSource">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" 
                text='<%# Eval("Value") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>

  <asp:SqlDataSource 
      ConnectionString=
          "<%$ _fill_in_your_string %>"
      ID="labelDataSource" runat="server" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Value from myTable">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Look here also: possible duplicate?    [How to add Repeater control dynamically from code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319074/how-to-add-repeater-control-dynamically-from-code-behind)