# add a checkbox or a radio button inside a repeater after checking a condion in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to add a radiobutton or checkbox dynamically for each record inside a repeater after checking a condition. depend on the condtion will decide what the control is... 
if the condition true then all the records should be with radio button else with checkboxes. i tried to add this condition to myRpt_ItemDataBound. but i got stuck. please help me.

.aspx code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRpt" runat="server" OnItemCommand="myRpt_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="myRpt_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr class="">
                <td>
                    Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Address
                </td>
                <td>
                    Age
                </td>
                <td>
                    Year
                </td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                    ** the place, I want to add the control **
                    // need  to add checkbox or radiobutton after checking the condition in code behind file
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("Name")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("Address")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("Age")%>&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Year")%>&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

in code behind file

```
public void BindUserData()
{
    myRpt.DataBind();
}

protected void myRpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        //check for condition
        if(*******)
        {
            //should add a radio button for the record
        }
        else
        {
            //shoud add a check box for the record
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly are you struggling with? How to add a control to the repeater row?

Comment: yes.. how can i add a checkbox or radiobutton as a repeater item in code behind page...? thanks for ur concern

Comment: may be this answer can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319074/how-to-add-repeater-control-dynamically-from-code-behind

Comment: But this is as simple as `e.Item.Controls.Add(new RadioButton())`, so what is your problem with here?

Comment: @user2837480 - So the options in both radio button and checkbox are going to be same or different?

Comment: @Andrei: yes thats true. but i want to add each control in front of the record. i mean how can i place it where i want to put it.? by giving id to div and then adding a control..? another thing is, if that condition is true, all the controls should be radio buttons, or else check boxes.

ex: (radiobtn) | Name | Address | Age ....
      (radiobtn) | Name | Address | Age ....
      (radiobtn) | Name | Address | Age ....

or 
    (checkbox) | Name | Address | Age ....
    (checkbox) | Name | Address | Age ....
    (checkbox) | Name | Address | Age ....

is this possible with a repeater...?

Comment: @RahulSingh: actually if there are radio buttons then i need one value. lets say a ID, user can pick only one name, if check boxes then user must select all the names from the repeater. so both behave like same.

Comment: @Navy thanks for the link. i will check it